# PHP Телеграм бот, как удалить inline-кнопку у всех касаемо отправленного сообщения?

Tags: php, telegram

Бэкенд отправляет сообщение с кнопкой всем chat_id в базе данных, и как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (кто первый нажимает) у всех эта кнопка касаемо данного сообщения удалилось или поменялось? message_id касается только самого юзера который нажимает, но у других не меняется кнопка

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49200399/13435478

Comment: Отредактировать сообщение, как указано выше, и добавить в логику бекенда проверку, чтобы отсеять тех, кто всё таки успел нажать на кнопку после